# AppCompat v7: Should I use Framework FragmentManager or SupportFragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-appcompat, fragmentmanager

I am making an app which should have minSdk = 15 and targetSdk = 21, therefore I want to use the features provided by the appcompat-v7 library.

I always wondered if I should use getFragmentManager or getSupportFragmentManager when using the supportlibrary-v7.

I am encountering a small problem now: when using getFragmentManager (and therefore using the framework fragments and fragmenttransaction) I wasnt able to pop the backstack by simply pressing the backbutton - I had to do a backStackCount > 0 check and manually popBackStack, otherwise my activity was simply finished. This problem was solved when I switched my small app to use the v4 classes (getSupportFragmentManager etc.). Which is fine I guess, but I would like to have a guideline/bestpractice to know which way to go and why

So, my Activity is inheriting from ActionBarActivity (according to [AppCompat-Blog-Entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)) and I am using the new toolbar, should I use only v4-Fragments(-Manager, -Transactions)?

I havent found any best practices or guidlines for that. And I am unsure about what to consider when deciding between these two :-/

Comment: I had the same problem in my applications and the answer is: use the classes that libraries provide about Fragments. Because there are some classes like [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) that you can only use with support libraries so it is wise to use all the classes that Support Libraries related to Fragments.

Comment: Actually there is a [v13.FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) which works with the framework Fragments. But still, this is not really a guideline IMO. As I said, I totally switched to v4 for consistency reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are inheriting your activities from `ActionBarActivity` you should always use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. It automatically forwards your calls to `getFragmentManager()` if the phone supports it (runs Honeycomb or later), otherwise it uses its compatibility implementation.

Comment: I use the appcompat-v7 not only because of Fragment support (I know that Fragment support was added prior to API 15). The main reason is because I want to use some features introduced in API 21, like the Toolbar or the MaterialDesign-Theme. So AFAIK I need to use the appcompat-v7.

Comment: In this case go for the `ActionBarActivity`. If you plan to use Toolbar you will quite likely need the `setActionBar(...)` method which is not available before API 21 - use `setSupportActionBar(...)` instead.

Comment: You are right, I need to use the `setSupportActionBar()` Method. So, basically, because of my usage of the AppCompat, I should use all the support methods?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Still this is not very satisfying because I still dont know why and when one need to use the support functions. I would accept your answer, but the last paragraph is wrong IMO.

Comment: For future reference: The support fragment manager within FragmentActivity does not forward any calls to the framework fragment manager. This can be seen in the sources (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java) and is stated in the docs: "When running on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still used; it does not try to switch to the framework's implementation." (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html)

Comment: Just use the regular fragment manager if you're using AppCompatActivity and targeting anything recent. The supportFragmentManager is only for backporting fragments to earlier apis.